# Select com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho um retorno json pelo Jquery e queria carregar o conteúdo em um campo select meu javascript tá assim:

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'Acoes.php',
            data: {'ACAO' : 'BUSCA_SETOR' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success :  function(response){

            for(var i=0; response.length>i; i++){
                $('#val_setor').append('<option value="'+response[i].SETOR+'">'+response[i].SETOR+'</option>');

            }


        },error: function(result) {
            alert("Data not found");
        }
});
```

Tentei `$('#val_setor').append` mas não funcionou.

Meu campo select é assim:

```
<select id="val_setor" name="val_setor" class="select-chosen" data-placeholder="ESCOLHA UM SETOR" style="width: 590px;">
                <option value="">ESCOLHA UM SETOR</option>
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
```

Como é a maneira correta de preencher?

Answer (score -1):

Isto deve funcionar:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Acoes.php',
  data: {
    'ACAO': 'BUSCA_SETOR'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    const valSetor = document.getElementById('val_setor')

    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      const option = document.createElement('option')
      option.value = response[i].SETOR
      option.text = response[i].SETOR

      valSetor.appendChild(option)
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('Data not found')
  }
})
```